# Order by (orderby) the sum of two columns in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am selecting from a table using LINQ.

I want to order by the sum of two columns.

Here is a simplified version of what isn't working for me

```
                List<DTO.Test> rtn = (from i in db.Table1
                                      orderby i.col1 + i.col2 descending
                                      select i).Take(200).ToList();
```

****** Edit - this is the full code

```
        List<DTO.Investigation> rtn = (from i in db.Investigations
                                   where i.IsDeleted == false
                                   orderby i.total + i.prevtotal descending
                                   select new DTO.Investigation()
                                   {
                                       InvestigationID = i.InvestigationID,
                                       InvestigationDate = i.InvestigationDate.Value,              
                                   }).Distinct().Take(200).ToList();
```

Comment: "what isn't working for me". And what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Sorry, it is just ordering by the first one "col1", so its not adding them together before ordering

Comment: Does the regular syntax work: `db.Table1.OrderByDescending(i => i.col1 + i.col2).Take(200)` work? If you get the same result then there is something in your data that is not what you believe it is.

Comment: `orderby i.col1 + i.col2 descending` orders by `i.col1 + i.col2`, nothing else. I think you oversimplified your query and you should show something that's closer to the real thing.

Comment: @S.Gray are you getting any kind of error? If yes, could you share the error message?

Comment: See the duplicate. That's why it's always risky to post excerpts of code, however appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your original question had `orderby col1 + col2 descending`, but the correct syntax for `orderby` is:

```
orderby i.col1 + i.col2 descending
```

Make sure you have `using System.Linq` near the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

A fully working solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (!db.People.Any())
            {
                db.People.Add(new Person { Name = "John", Score1 = 5, Score2 = 1 });
                db.People.Add(new Person { Name = "Mary", Score1 = 2, Score2 = 5 });
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            // Query Syntax
            List<PersonDto> results = (from p in db.People
                                       orderby p.Score1 + p.Score2 descending
                                       select new PersonDto { Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name, TotalScore = p.Score1 + p.Score2 })
                                   .Take(200)
                                   .ToList();

            // Method Syntax
            List<PersonDto> results2 = db.People
                .OrderByDescending(p => p.Score1 + p.Score2)
                .Select(p => new PersonDto { Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name, TotalScore = p.Score1 + p.Score2 })
                       .Take(200)
                       .ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("{0,-5}{1,-10}{2,-10}", "Id", "Name", "TotalScore");
            foreach (var item in results1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-5}{1,-10}{2,-10}", item.Id, item.Name, item.TotalScore);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext() : base(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=Db63409328; Integrated Security=true")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Score1 { get; set; }
        public int Score2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int TotalScore { get; set; }
    }
}
```